# Not able to access nested Object elements

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I am new to php specially OOP.
I need to access nested object elements.
`MyNewJamaContourServiceGet` is the class whose object is $jama
`Print_r($jama)`gives this object structure :

```
MyNewJamaContourServiceGet Object
(
    [result:JamaContourWsdlClass:private] => JamaContourStructGetItemsFromTextSearchResponse Object
        (
            [return] => JamaContourStructGetItemsFromTextSearchResponse Object
                (
                    [return] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => JamaContourStructWsItem Object
                                (
                                    [childDocumentTypeId] =>
                                    [createdDate] => 2014-03-08
                                    [currentUserWritePermissions] =>
```

I tried accessing it like :

```
 var_dump($jama->result->JamaContourWsdlClass);
   var_dump($jama['result:JamaContourWsdlClass']['return']['return'][0]['JamaContourStructWsItem']['createdDate']);
```

It gives NULL. What i'm doing wrong.
I also tried converting it to array with type casting and `json_encode(json_decode($jama));` but no luck.

MODIFIED :
As suggested by the Dev.Bushido I modified $result to public now i get following object :

```
MyNewJamaContourServiceGet Object
(
    [result] => JamaContourStructGetItemsFromTextSearchResponse Object
        (
            [return] => JamaContourStructGetItemsFromTextSearchResponse Object
                (
                    [return] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => JamaContourStructWsItem Object
                                (
                                    [childDocumentTypeId] =>
                                    [createdDate] => 2014-03-08T01:21:18.867Z
                                    [currentUserWritePermissions] =>
```

I tried accessing it with following :

```
var_dump($jama['result']['return']['return'][0]['createdDate']);

 var_dump($jama->{'result'}->{'return'}['return'][0]['JamaContourStructWsItem']['createdDate']);
```

Why i am still not able to access them as they are not private anymore?

Thanks a lot Dev.Bushido! :)
Here is the function which i added in the class to search for key in object to retrieve it's value :

```
    class MyNewJamaContourServiceGet extends JamaContourServiceGet{



            public function findValue($jama, $key)
            {
    #           if(array_key_exists($key, $jamaContourServiceGet))
    #           return true;
                    echo "before foreach";
                    foreach($jama as $key1 => $value1)
                    {
                            echo "Inside foreach Key1 value is : ". $key1;
                            echo "Vlaue1 is : ". $value1;
                            if (in_array($key, $value1))
                            {
                                    echo "return value1 is : ". $value1;
                                    return $value1;
                            }
                            elseif(is_array($value1))
                            {
                                    echo "Inside elseif value1 is an ARRAY : ". $value1;
                                    return findValue($value1, $key);
                            }
                    }

             return false;
            }
}

$key ="label";
$r1=$jama->findValue($jama,$key);

if($r1)
{
    echo "The element is in the array" . "\n";
    echo $key ." : " . $r1 . "\n";
} else  {
            echo "Key not found ";
            echo $r1;
        }
```

Is this function right ? as only `echo before foreach` get executed and i get key not found.

I updated my function as you said :

```
class MyNewJamaContourServiceGet extends JamaContourServiceGet{

  private $test;
        public function Add($add){
                $this->test=$add;
        }

        public function FindValue1($object, $key)
        {
                echo "Inside FindValue1 \n";
                echo "before if \n ";
            if (is_null($object->{$key})){
                echo "It is null \n";
                    return false;
                } else if (is_object($object->{$key})){
                        echo "inside else if \n";
                        return FindValue1($object->{$key}, $key);
                  }
                    return $object->{$key};
        }
}

$test = new MyNewJamaContourServiceGet($wsdl);
$testTest = new MyNewJamaContourServiceGet($wsdl);

$testTest->Add(0);
$test->Add($testTest);

var_dump($test->findValue1($test,'label'));
```

I get the result as :

Inside FindValue1
before if

```
Notice: Undefined property: MyNewJamaContourServiceGet::$label in /opt/lampp/htdocs/JAMA/jamaContour/test_import.php on line 107
It is null
bool(false)
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

properties of an object are accessed differently then you're doing right now.

try:

```
var_dump(var_dump($jama->result->return->return[0]->createdDate);
```

Is this the function you want:

```
public function FindValue($object, $key)
{
    if (is_null($object->{$key})){
        return false;
    } else if (is_object($object->{$key})){
        return $this->FindValue($object->{$key}, $key);
    }

    return $object->{$key};
}
```

Comment: @user3520135 can you add the code of your class if this doesn't work, because the problem might lie somewhere else.

Comment: It's is working but i think i should add a function in the main class to get value just like you said. As making $result public is not good.

Comment: If you want to add a function that returns the value of the result, then you should add it in the MyNewJamaContourServiceGet class, otherwise you would have the same problem again ;)

Comment: Actually what i am actually doing is trying to search for key in this object and return that key's value. so i added a function of findvalue in MyNewJamaContourServiceGet  class but it was not getting executed.I will try it now i think it's shouldn't have any problem now. I will add the function code in the question.

Comment: Thanks ! but Nope this doesn't work i think because of Array's inside objects. and yes i want to  search object with key parameter and return value of the key.

Comment: My testcase did work though http://pastebin.com/4vhAR6EP, maybe you can use it to develop your function.